# Assigning autoreleased object to a strong object

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Lets say I have a class A with a member variable "myDictionary".

Now if I do this:

```
myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionary];
```

I know that by default members of a class are of strong type. So myDictionary will be available during the lifetime of class A object. Thats what my understanding is about ARC.

But I am getting an `EXE_BAC_ACCESS` on myDictionary which really confuses me. Do I need to do anything extra in order to avoid `EXE_BAD_EXCESS` on myDictionary? Because above method returns an autoreleased object.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show the stacktrace and more of the relevant code.

Comment: myDictionary is it ivar ?

Answer (score 0):

> If you're not using ARC, then you should use +dictionary any time you
>   need an autoreleased dictionary, and +alloc/init any time you need a
>   dictionary that you're going to hold on to (e.g. by placing it in an
>   ivar), or alternatively if you simply want to avoid autorelease and
>   -release it manually.

So try to implement like this:

```
myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: The OP implies he is using ARC with the statement "I know that by default members of a class are of strong type", so I don't see how your answer solves anything.  The question is misleading and needs clarification before it can be answered properly.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely error here is accessing `myDictionary` from multiple threads. Ensuring that you always access ivar correctly is one of the several reasons you should always refer to your properties as `self.myDictionary` rather than directly referring to the `_myDictionary` ivar. When you need to make this thread-safe, that will ensure there is only one place you need to fix the code.

There are other possible ways to get this error, such as incorrect handling of `CFBridging...` functions, but the most common is multi-threaded access.